# wordpress page.php styling and markup

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a couple of questions related to building a custom theme with Wordpress.

1) If the website is made up of pages, I can use page .php to run the LOOP and retrieve content. In this case, is it OK to paste the content (of each page) using the backend of word press - I.e. paste all content **and** HTML markup into the 'text; . Is this a reliable way to enter content and accompanying markup into the database?

I guess the advantage is that users will then be able to edit the content themselves using the visual Tab.

Many thanks,
P

Answer (score 0):

Well this not a recommended way to do it, but yes the editor is there for the same purpose. I wont be using it this way, because in my experience wordpress editor often acts weird with html. By default auto paragraphs are enabled, so everything gets in its own paragraph, even if you disable auto paragraph it still has some issues. For instance if you add html in the text tab, and then goto visual tab and switch back to html, and save the same html, this time it would be styled differently. Secondly its also not good to allow users to add html from a security POV and you cant guarentee the consitency of the website.

I would recommend using custom fields instead and fetch these custom fields in the through your theme files.